# Loading message while loading javascript iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, loading

I have a code like this:

```
<div class=scrbbl-embed data-src=/event/1234/5678></div>                
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js,ijs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(d.getElementById(id))return;
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src="http://embed.scribblelive.com/widgets/embed.js";
        ijs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ijs);
    }(document, 'script', 'scrbbl-js'));
</script>
```

And I would like to add some kind of loading message while its loading.

The question is, how should I do it?

Comment: should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587253/how-do-i-add-a-loading-indicator-to-my-page-while-my-iframe-loads

Comment: but its not the iframe so I think that I cant "listen" to iframe.load ? am I right?

Comment: 3rd party site, not going to know when it loads...

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe load function which is triggered when iframe is loaded and before that you can show loading message.

$('iframe').load(function(){});